# Do we use articles with the word "attire?"

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

Do we use articles like **a** with the word "attire?"
For instance, would you say, "I'm sure she'd look great in **a** black attire?"

Comment: She was attired in black. But no a in black attire. We'd probably say: dressed in black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No article, as attire is uncountable when used this way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'Attire' is an uncountable noun. Therefore, using the article 'a' just before it or either 'a' or 'an' before the adjective that precedes it is wrong.